# Error message when saving

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am using SharePoint Designer to create and edit a new Masterpage. I often save my dox to test css and other updates, however I usually get an error message as I save that reads:

"An error occurred while attempting to write the new file.
The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."

Is anyone else getting this on a consistent basis? I can cancel the error message try my save again. Sometimes it allows me to save, while other times I get the error message again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probable that the conflict is with your anti-virus program, or some other process that is using that file at the time it is being saved.

Oh, and Mr. Camden-Wyoming Delaware, I am a little disappointed that you never once used 'SharePointy'. *tsk tsk tsk* Your mother would be ashamed.